# Internet vocabulary: Is 落ちる an equivalent of "being AFK"?

Tags: meaning, internet-slang

### Context

I saw many times people using 落ちる in a chat followed by 後で. I assumed that the user expressed his intent of temporarily leaving a chat and planned to come back later.

### Question

- As the title mentions, is 落ちます an equivalent of "AFK<sup>1</sup>" with the underlying meaning of coming back later on?
- Is there a way to differentiate **"I got to go"** (*I don't plan to come back*) and **"I'll be back"** (*I temporarily leave the chat/game/whatever*)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>**AFK**: **A**way **F**rom **K**eyboard</sub>

Comment: For the sake of clarity maybe you should specify what AFK means for people not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: @Tommy totally correct. I just added the acronym definition assuming that it would be enough, especially on the point that the leaving is *temporarily* only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

落ちます is closer to "gotta go now." It usually means *not* returning for the day, unless otherwise modified by しばらく, ちょっと, 30分くらい, 飯食ってくるので, etc. A typical response for 落ちます would be おやすみなさい, また明日, お疲れ様, etc.

後で usually indicates the person who said this somehow knows the other person is coming back relatively soon. It's not a typical response for 落ちます modified by nothing.

If you want to explicitly say "I'll be back", you can use すぐ戻ります, ちょっと外します, しばらく落ちます, etc. Many online gamers will understand "AFK", too.

Comment: `Many online gamers will understand "AFK"` -- ちなみにですけど・・・"BRB"も、通じます？日本人（のゲーマー？）の間でも、"brb"ってよく使われてますか？

Comment: たぶんAFKとかLOLとかよりはずっと知名度低い気がします。

Comment: @naruto Thanks for your answer. I did not notice how the *modifier* such as `しばらく` were important

Comment: @Chocolate I'll comment in English as my Japanese grammar is clumsy. I would like to add that I feel a [subtle difference between **AFK** and **BRB**](https://obviate.io/2009/08/03/brb-versus-afk/). I personally expect *BRB* to be short and not necessarily AFK (example: I'm switching to another application) and usually expect AFK to be a justification: `AFK drink` (so about few minutes), `AFK groceries` (maybe an hour) or a duration `AFK 5 min`.

Comment: @Al1 ありがとうございます。上手く使い分けするのはとても難しそうですけど、がんばります＾＾

Answer (score 3):

落ちる could refer to the Internet connection, meaning the person will leave and therefore the connection will drop.

I'm taking liberties here but you can think of it as

> （今日のところはこれで。ネット接続が）落ちます。（また）後で。

Comment: `今日のところでこれで` <-- You meant to say 「今日のところ**は**これで。」, no?

Comment: @keithmaxx Thanks for your answer and example is appreciated. However, I have to confess that naruto's answer rather fit what I have met